# Erro ao tentar salvar informações na base de dados por meio do Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, winforms, entity-framework-6

Meu projeto possui as seguintes classes:

```
public class Manifestacao
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string NumeroChamado { get; set; }
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Conteudo> Conteudos { get; set; }
}

public class Conteudo
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Categoria { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoria { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Obs { get; set; }
    public string Evidencias { get; set; }

    public long UsuarioAberturaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario UsuarioAbertura { get; set; }

    public long UsuarioFechamentoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario UsuarioFechamento { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DataHoraAbertura { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataHoraFechamento { get; set; }

    public long ManifestacaoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Manifestacao Manifestacao { get; set; }
}

public class Usuario
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Apelido { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Categoria { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

A intenção é pegar os dados inseridos em um form e salvá-los no banco de dados por meio do Entity Framework. Alguns dados do form estão em textboxes e outros no datagridview. O usuário responsável por salvar as informações também é registrado, até ai tudo bem. Instancio os objetos pegando as informações do form, conforme o código a seguir:

```
        var cliente = new Cliente
        {
            Empresa = txtEmpresaCliente.Text,
            Contato = txtContatoCliente.Text,
            Email = txtEmailCliente.Text,
            Telefone = mskTelefoneCliente.Text,
            Ramal = txtRamalCliente.Text,
            Celular = mskCelularCliente.Text
        };

        List<Conteudo> conteudosDgv = new List<Conteudo>();
        List<string> listaSubCategorias = new List<string>();            

        DateTime dataHoraAbertura = PegaDataHoraUsuario.DataHoraPadrao();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvRegistros.Rows)
        {
            Conteudo conteudoLinha = new Conteudo();
            conteudoLinha.Categoria = (string)row.Cells["categoria"].Value;
            conteudoLinha.SubCategoria = (string)row.Cells["subcategoria"].Value;
            conteudoLinha.Descricao = (string)row.Cells["descricao"].Value;
            conteudoLinha.Status = "Novo";
            conteudoLinha.UsuarioAbertura = dalUsuario.GetUsuarioByID(UsuarioLogado.Id);
            conteudoLinha.DataHoraAbertura = dataHoraAbertura;
            conteudosDgv.Add(conteudoLinha);

            listaSubCategorias.Add(conteudoLinha.SubCategoria);
        }
        var manifestacao = new Manifestacao
        {
            Cliente = cliente,
            Conteudos = conteudosDgv,
            NumeroChamado = PegaDataHoraUsuario.nChamado(),
        };
        using (var context = new EFContext())
        {
            context.Manifestacoes.Add(manifestacao);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
```

Ao tentar executar o trecho que salva os dados, é acusado o erro:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Conteudoes_dbo.Usuarios_UsuarioFechamentoId' on table 'Conteudoes' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.'
```

Adicionei as anotações de ForeignKey conforme a [documentação do EF](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) na classe Conteudo:

```
    [ForeignKey("UsuarioAbertura")]
    public long UsuarioAberturaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario UsuarioAbertura { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UsuarioFechamento")]
    public long UsuarioFechamentoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario UsuarioFechamento { get; set; }
```

Mas mesmo assim o mesmo erro persiste.

Comment: Uma coisa eu sei que já está incorreta. A anotação `ForeignKey` deve estar sobre a propriedade que representa o objeto, no caso, UsuarioAbertura e UsuarioFechamento. E ela também deve apontar para o campo no banco que será a chave estrangeira, no caso, UsuarioAberturaId  e UsuarioFechamentoId. Se continuar tendo problema é por haver mais erros, vai postando que tentamos ajudar.

Comment: Então, mas segundo a documentação a anotação pode ser feita de forma inversa. tem até um exemplo demonstrando: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Entendi, não conhecia realmente desta forma. Sempre fiz dessa outra. Então deve ser outra coisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 [ForeignKey("UsuarioAbertura")]
 public long UsuarioAberturaId { get; set; }
 public virtual Usuario UsuarioAbertura { get; set; }
```

Aqui você tentou mapear uma relação de 1 para 1? Se tentou esta incorreto, isso é uma fração da configuração que faz a relação de 1 para N, e isso é suficiente para o Entity entender esse relacionamento na hora de criar/editar o banco.

Recomendo: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

O problema é que a exclusão em cascata esta ativa. Quando você mandar Manifestação deletar, ele vai sair deletando todos Conteudos relacionados e o mesmo vai sair deletando todos Usuario vinculado, porém eu tenho 2 relacionamentos para Usuario, onde os dois lados da relação pode sair derrubando as mesmas tabelas e vai ocorrer esse conflito que o Entity Framework acusou.

```
Manifestacao 
-->> DROP CASCADE Conteudo
     -->> DROP CASCADE Usuario (possui dois relacionamento "iguais" a sofrer exclusão)
          -->> UsuarioAbertura
          -->> UsuarioFechamento
```

A solução é arrumar esse relacionamento caso a intenção seja de 1 para 1 e caso seja de 1 para N você vai ter que usar o Fluent API para configurar que não é uma exclusão em cascata ou utilizar a seguinte linha para excluir a convenção de CASCADE DELETE no `OnModelCreating()`:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

Comment: Obrigado, Gabriel!